# Can you use the Blob brush in illustrator to add to an existing "blob" with a gradient color?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I drew a "blob" or a sketch and then colored it with a linear gradient. I then selected the eye-dropper tool and picked that same gradient.

After having the gradient set as my fill color I attempt to draw and add to the blob but it does not add to the existing image. Instead the previous color is drawn (not the gradient) and the new blob is not attached to the old one.

Is there a way to draw and expand an existing blob with a gradient applied?

For reference:

**Before drawing with gradient**
[image]

**After drawing with gradient**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Set the gradient to the **stroke** before using the Blob Brush. (only possible in CS6+)

The Blob Brush uses the stroke color as the end fill color. Setting a fill color is not applied when using the Blob Brush.

Comment: I'm using CS5, aaand that sucks, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that you can append blobs to existing shapes when you reset them to a simple appearance. In my case I had to remove a brush stroke and reapply it after making blob brush edits. Not sure if this is intended or a bug. (Illustrator CC 2019)